# WPF application stops interacting on screen rotate

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, non-interactive

We have a WPF app which runs fine, but a user reported that it locks up when the screen is rotated.  (Tablets will do that!)

The app actually renders fully after the rotate but stops responding to the mouse/keyboard.  It doesn't show as 'non-responding' in a Windows sense.

We can simulate the "lock up" here, but debugging this is odd:

- Lock up does not occur while in VS debugger
- If you try and attach to the locked up process, VS says the process was built without debug information
- Before the lockup VS can attach/deattach to the same EXE process

We have put trace outputs in global unhandled exceptions but nothing is fired.

I can only think of one next step to debug which is start to hack out chunks of code and find the breaking area.

Anyone seen this before or got any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with an update library we were using called [Sparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/).

It was creating a hidden WinForms form in it's constructor.  There must be some kind of WPF/WinForms interop bug during screen rotations.  Removing that form or removing the library fixed the issue.